# Magento 2 Custom Module Not Accessible In Other Users

Tags: magento2, php, acl

I have simple grid listing custom module in magento 2 admin, but I can not access it in other users then default admin,

Here are my files

**acl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Spaarg_Tables::tables" title="tables" sortOrder="100"/>
 <!--AddMenuAcl-->
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Spaarg. All rights reserved.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Spaarg_Tables::spaarg_tablesgrid_index" title="Tables" module="Spaarg_Tables"  sortOrder="20" dependsOnModule="Spaarg_Tables" action="tables/tablesgrid/index" resource="Spaarg_Tables::spaarg_tablesgrid_index"/>
<!--AddMenu-->
    </menu>
</config>
```

**system.xml**

Here is my controller **Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Spaarg\Tables\Controller\Adminhtml\TablesGrid;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;


class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    protected $resultPage;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $this->resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();  
        $this->resultPage->setActiveMenu('Spaarg_TablesGrid::tables');
        $this->resultPage ->getConfig()->getTitle()->set((__('TablesGrid')));
        return $this->resultPage;
    }

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
      return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Spaarg_TablesGrid::tables');
    }

}
```

It is showing checked in user roles for my modules, I am new to magento, it would be great if someone can suggest a way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Spaarg_Tables::tables" title="tables" sortOrder="100"/>
 <!--AddMenuAcl-->
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Spaarg. All rights reserved.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Spaarg_Tables::spaarg_tablesgrid_index" title="Tables" module="Spaarg_Tables"  sortOrder="20" dependsOnModule="Spaarg_Tables" action="tables/tablesgrid/index" resource="Spaarg_Tables::tables"/>
<!--AddMenu-->
    </menu>
</config>
```

Then assign permission to  the Role.

Note: clear cache

Comment: Worked perfectly. Great help. Thanks for your quick response.